# Sinch iOS app : Identifying if the app receives video or voice call

Tags: ios, swift, sinch

I have integrated a video call with voice call in sinch on swift project.  But the problem is , in the `appDelegate` I have a function `didReceiveIncomingCall`. How can I put some code inside this function to determine if the call is voice call to show `voiceCallVC` or if the call is videoCall to show `VideoVC`.

```
  func client(_ client: SINCallClient!, didReceiveIncomingCall call: SINCall!) {


        var top = self.window?.rootViewController

        while (top?.presentedViewController != nil) {
            top = top?.presentedViewController
        }

        let videoVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "videoVC") as! VideoCallVC
        videoVC._call = call
        top?.present(videoVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        let callVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CallVC") as! VoiceCallVC
        callVC._call = call
        top?.present(callVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check For the Bool value `'call.details.isVideoOffered'`

Here is the Code For This

```
    func client(_ client: SINCallClient!, didReceiveIncomingCall call: SINCall!) {

     var top = self.window?.rootViewController

     while (top?.presentedViewController != nil) {
        top = top?.presentedViewController
       }
        if (call.details.isVideoOffered)
        {
            let videoVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "videoVC") as! VideoCallVC
            videoVC._call = call
            top?.present(videoVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            let callVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CallVC") as! VoiceCallVC
           callVC._call = call
           top?.present(callVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

  }
```